# change harddisk order before system boots (with kernel command line options)

Tags: kernel, boot, hard-disk

I have one hard disk connected through onboard SATA, and another through SAS raid controller.

The disk connected through raid controller appears as `/dev/sda`, and the onboart SATA disk as `/dev/sdb`.

I need to change this, os that SATA disk is `/dev/sda`.

I need to change this before the system boots (not with udev later).

So it appears to me that the only way to achieve this is via kernel commandline options.

I have found exactly same question [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/67778)

with solution to change module loading order with:

```
rdloaddriver=ata_piix,hpsa,qla2xxx,lpfc,megaraid_sas,sata_sil24
```

But by kernel doea not use loadable modules. I have all drivers compiled in statically.

How can I change the order of my HDDs, specifically so that SATA comes before RAID controller ?